# Visual studio and alpha backgrounds

Tags: vb.net, png, alpha-transparency

Seen this question asked a lot but can't seem to find an answer. So here it is. Can you use a PNG with an alpha channel as the background image for a VB app? I don't care about changing the shape of the app rectangle is fine. They just want to use a character with a drop shadow behind him as the background for the app.

Comment: sorry should have said, I forget that VB comes in various forms now. This is in VB 2008, winforms, .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinForms, you'll need to make a layered window.
In WPF, you'll need to set `AllowsTransparency` to true and `WindowStyle` to `None`.

Comment: Hhmm might have problems with that then. The brief I have only goes to .Net 2.0, I think we are going to have to go with opaque backgrounds. Thanks though.